# Why my Ariba cannot parse my response API?

Tags: sap-ariba, cxml-commercexml

My Ariba network cannot parse my document cXML response. At Ariba screen I have this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cXML payloadID="1501467044460-2947794417638298020@216.109.111.19" timeStamp="2017-07-30T19:10:44-07:00">
   <Response>
      <Status code="200" text="OK" />
      <PunchOutSetupResponse>
         <StartPage>
            <URL>test.ariba.com</URL>
         </StartPage>
      </PunchOutSetupResponse>
   </Response>
</cXML>
```

However I still get this message from Ariba:

> Couldn't parse document

Can anyone support me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the document we're using and working correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML timestamp="<%= @timestamp %>" payloadID="<%= @payload_id %>">
  <Response>
    <Status code="200" text="success"></Status>
    <PunchOutSetupResponse>
      <StartPage>
        <URL><%= @start_url %></URL>
      </StartPage>
    </PunchOutSetupResponse>
  </Response>
</cXML>
```

The start_url must be a valid URL like `http://test.mysite.com/xxxxx`

Comment: if this <!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd"> necessary or not

Answer (score 0):

could you check if there is language dependency. lang="en-US"

Comment: in my cXML response there is no lang attribute to modified so that maybe not that problem

Comment: please go thought the link once : 
https://success.coupa.com/Suppliers/Integration_Resources/Sample_Punchout_Setup_Request

is it possible to send internal errors from ariba system

otherwise you were missing the catalog redirection complete url : 
<URL>test.ariba.com/catalog redirection here</URL>

Comment: Thank you your answers make me okie now